# Python Manage Repositories Pycharm

Tags: python, repository, package, pycharm, pypi

I have recently had to re-download and install Python by using the Anaconda package. This was done because i was having issues installing a few packages and found sources saying it would be easier to simply do it using Anaconda.

I now have the issue that I am unable to upgrade or find new packages (which i used to be able to do, i think it gave the list of all Pypi packages) and am not sure which URL i need to enter in order for PyCharm to find all the packages that it used to. This is what i currently have in the Repositories, As you can see i have already added a few PyPi links, of which none have been successful:

[image]

Does anyone know what link needs to be entered here to be able to browse through all PyPi Packages or upgrade currently installed packages?

Answer (score 14):

Under `Project Interpreter`, there is an Anaconda button. This is a toggle. Turning it off, allows you to use repositories like `https://pypi.python.org/simple`.

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration i have :

https://pypi.python.org/simple

I've had the same problem after installing Anaconda because of a tkinter problem

[image]

Comment: I added the same repository url, but still Selenium didn't show up in the list. Surfing to the URL shows Selenium just fine. But opening the terminal (which had the conda env activated) made it possible to pip install selenium. Now Selenium shows up in the list of 'installed packages', but still not in 'available packages'.